# How can I optimize this Sierpinski carpet i made using recursion?

Tags: recursion, processing, fractals

I followed the Shiffmans tutorial about recursion to end up with this:[image: Sierpinski carpet i made]

As you can see its not perfect and I think the code can be optimized. How do I get rid of the thick lines that should´t be there? And if you get an idea of how I could optimize this code tell me please!

This was made with processing 3.3.6 and the code is the following:

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();

  rectMode(CENTER);
  Serpinski(width/2, height/2, width/3);
}

void Serpinski(int x, int y, int d) {
  rect(x, y, d, d);
  if (d > 1) {
    Serpinski(int(x+ d), y, d*1/3);
    Serpinski(int(x- d), y, d*1/3);
    Serpinski(x, int(y+ d), d*1/3);
    Serpinski(x, int(y- d), d*1/3);
    Serpinski(int(x+ d), int(y+ d), d*1/3);
    Serpinski(int(x- d), int(y- d), d*1/3);
    Serpinski(int(x+ d), int(y- d), d*1/3);
    Serpinski(int(x- d), int(y+ d), d*1/3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the "thick" white lines that appear at the borders of the topmost 3x3 grid? My guess is that they are just due to rounding errors: 800 / 3 = 266,666667 (truncated to 266 for `int`), 266 / 3 = 88,6666667 (truncated to 88 for `int`). I guess the parameters of the `Sierpinski` function should be `float`. (This is not an answer, because I cannot really test this, but if you confirm that it works, I'd write it as an answer (and maybe also try it out...))

Comment: instead of drawing white lines, try cutting out black rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, changing the Sierpinski method so it deals with *float* values instead of *int* will help.

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  rectMode(CENTER);
  Serpinski(width/2, height/2, width/3);
}

void Serpinski(float x, float y, float d) {
  rect(x, y, d, d);
  if (d > 1) {
    Serpinski( x+ d,  y,    d/3);
    Serpinski( x- d,  y,    d/3);
    Serpinski( x,     y+ d, d/3);
    Serpinski( x,     y- d, d/3);
    Serpinski( x+ d,  y+ d, d/3);
    Serpinski( x- d,  y- d, d/3);
    Serpinski( x+ d,  y- d, d/3);
    Serpinski( x- d,  y+ d, d/3);
  }
}
```

However, due to [the way the pixel information is handled](http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/c2/s1.html), you will find that the graphic representation is still not "exact" when you get down to the smaller rectangles. One way to achieve that is to change the size of the sketch to one that is a power of 3:

```
size(729, 729);
```

As for optimization, you could call the Sierpinski method in *setup()*, that way it only gets computed once rather than every time *draw()* is called.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
void setup() {
  size(729, 729);
  fill(0);
  background(255);
  centerRectangle(0, 0, width);
  rectangles(width/3, height/3, width/3);
}

void centerRectangle(int x, int y, int s) {
  float delta = s/3;
  noStroke();
  rect(x+delta, y+delta, delta, delta);
}

void rectangles(int x, int y, int s) {
  if (s < 1) return;
  int xc = x-s;
  int yc = y-s;
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      if (!(row == 1 && col == 1)) {
        int xx = xc+row*s;
        int yy = yc+col*s;
        centerRectangle(xx, yy, s);
        rectangles(xx+s/3, yy+s/3, s/3);
      }
    }
  }
}
```